# Deduction of array continuously using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array values from the database

```
#    amount   deduction
[0]   50        10
[1]   300       20
[2]   200       30
```

I want to have a recursive deduction of these arrays until data is zero, and then if the first amount of the array is zero(0) the deduction will add to the next data, and then if the second amount is zero(0) the first and second deduction will add to the third amount and so on, until all amount will be zero (0). But if the third amount will be zero(0) the deduction should be added to the second deduction.

```
  [0]          [1]          [2]
50  - 10     300 - 20     200 - 30
40  - 10     280 - 20     170 - 30
30  - 10     260 - 20     140 - 30
20  - 10     240 - 20     110 - 30
10  - 10     220 - 20      80 - 30
 0           200 - 30      50 - 30
             170 - 30      20 - 30
             140 - 30       0 -  0
             110 - 60
              50 - 60
               0
```

**This is my code so far**

```
$data = json_decode($debtsData, true);
$continue = true;
while($continue) {
    $continue = max(array_column($data, 'amount')) > 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($data); ++$i) {
        $totalInterest = $data[$i]['interest_rate'] / 100;
        $periods = 12;
        $monthly = $data[$i]['monthly'];
        $_new_balance = !isset($data[$i]['done']) ? max($data[$i]['amount'], 0) : '';
        $interestPayment = ($totalInterest / $periods ) * $_new_balance;

        if($data[$i]['amount'] <= 0 && !isset($data[$i]['done'])) {
          $data[$i]['done'] = true;
          if(isset($data[$i+1])) {
             $data[$i+1]['monthly'] += $data[$i]['monthly'];
          }
        }

        echo !isset($data[$i]['done']) ? '$'.number_format(max($data[$i]['amount'], 0),2) : '';
        echo !isset($data[$i]['done']) ? '$'.number_format($data[$i]['monthly'],2) : '';
        echo !isset($data[$i]['done']) ? '$'.number_format($interestPayment,2).' ' : '';

        $data[$i]['amount'] -= $data[$i]['monthly'] - $interestPayment ;
     }
}
```

The problem of my code is that if my third amount will end zero(0) than the second amount, it will not add to the second deduction.

*PS: just don't mind the interest variable on my code*

Comment: when 3rd column reaches 0, why you don't add 30 to 2nd in your example?

Comment: is this what you want? https://3v4l.org/umLQE

Comment: @IłyaBursov sorry I updated my question. Didn't notice my calculation.

Comment: @angelloucelle check my comment too. above than your comment

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant Hi, thank you so much for your code but it is already close sir. But if the first is already zero sir the deduction should be added to the second one.

Comment: I'll give you a hint - to determine the remaining amount, you don't actually need to loop and subtract. You can use the module operator to determine what the remainder would be for `200 - 30` in a single calculation.

Comment: Could you provide another example? The logic that this is supposed to follow isn't clear because each `amount - deduction` has a remainder of 0, so it's not apparent which values are supposed to carry over to which next calculation.

Comment: @angelloucelle  give an example of your second statement: ___But if the first is already zero sir the deduction should be added to the second one___

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant I gave and example on my question sir. Above of the code there's a sample table of deduction.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones example: first data is 50 - 20, second data 80 - 10 and third data is 30 - 10. If the first data is done subtracting or <= 0, the 20 will be added to the second deduction.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the logic exactly should be when index `2` is done - should it try going backwards 1 (from index `2` to `1`), or forwards until it reaches a non-done value (from index `2` to `0`, but index `0` is already done, so `0` to `1`).

Regardless, the specific issue in the question's code is because it's only trying to go up an index:

```
if(isset($data[$i+1])) {
    $data[$i+1]['monthly'] += $data[$i]['monthly'];
}
```

It probably makes sense to separate that logic out into a `getNextKey()` function so you can determine the logic there. Something like:

```
function getNextKey($array, $i) {
    if (isset($array[$i+1]) && !$array[$i+1]['done']) {
        return $i+1;
    } else if (isset($array[$i-1]) && !$array[$i-1]['done']) {
        return $i-1;
    }

    // in this case, both the next and previous indices are already done, so the calculation is complete
    return -1;
}
```

`$continue = max(array_column($data, 'amount')) > 0;` should be after the `for` loop, not before. Otherwise you'll end up with one extra iteration when everything is already 0.

What's also not clear is at which point the remainder carries over to the next index. In the example, in step 5, index `0` calculates to 0, so I would think that in that step the amount would be added to index `1`'s calculation. But that doesn't seem to be the case in the example, so you'll need a separate variable to keep track of that carry-over for the next loop.

To clarify, look at the step with `10 - 10`. The *next* step is when `10` gets added to index `1`'s remainder. But then why for index `2` when it's `20 - 30` does it take 2 steps to carry over to index `1`'s remainder? It's not clear what `0 - 0` represents there, because I'd expect the previous step to determine that it's "done". e.g. I'd expect `140 - 60`, not `140 - 30` and then `110 - 60`.

Anyway, here's what I consider a working version based on the assumptions I made above: https://3v4l.org/OGU3u

```
<?php

$array = [
    0=>[
        'amount' => 50,
        'deduction' => 10
    ],
    1=>[
        'amount' => 300,
        'deduction' => 20
    ],
    2=>[
        'amount' => 200,
        'deduction' => 30
    ]
];

$finalArray = [];

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $array[$key]['done'] = false; // keep track of which values are done
    $array[$key]['remainder'] = 0; // carry over from other calculations
}

$continue = true;
while ($continue) {
    // reset remainders (calculated at the end of this step)
    $nextRemainders = array_fill(0, 3, 0);
    
    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
        // skip already-completed arrays
        if ($array[$i]['done'] == true) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $subtract = $array[$i]['deduction'] + $array[$i]['remainder'];
        
        // for debugging
        $key = $array[$i]['amount'] . ' - ' . $subtract; 
        
        if ($array[$i]['amount'] > $subtract) {
            // subtract the deduction and remainder
            $array[$i]['amount'] -= $subtract;
            
            // append calculation to our final array
            $finalArray[$i][$key] = $array[$i]['amount'];
        } else {
            $array[$i]['done'] = true;
            
            // set this value to 0 even if the calculation would leave it negative
            $array[$i]['amount'] = 0;
            
            // append calculation to our final array so we can track the steps
            $finalArray[$i][$key] = $array[$i]['amount'];
            
            $nextKey = getNextKey($array, $i);
            
            // no more values to calculate, done!
            if ($nextKey !== -1) {
                // add this deduction to the next step's calculation
                $nextRemainders[$nextKey] += $array[$i]['deduction'];
            }
        }
    }
    
    // check next remainders here and apply to the next step
    for($j=0; $j<count($nextRemainders); $j++) {
        $array[$j]['remainder'] += $nextRemainders[$j];
    }
    
    $continue = max(array_column($array, 'amount')) > 0;
}

function getNextKey($array, $i) {
    if (isset($array[$i+1]) && !$array[$i+1]['done']) {
        return $i+1;
    } else if (isset($array[$i-1]) && !$array[$i-1]['done']) {
        return $i-1;
    }
    
    return -1;
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Which has the following calculations:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [50 - 10] => 40
            [40 - 10] => 30
            [30 - 10] => 20
            [20 - 10] => 10
            [10 - 10] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [300 - 20] => 280
            [280 - 20] => 260
            [260 - 20] => 240
            [240 - 20] => 220
            [220 - 20] => 200
            [200 - 30] => 170
            [170 - 30] => 140
            [140 - 60] => 80
            [80 - 60] => 20
            [20 - 60] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [200 - 30] => 170
            [170 - 30] => 140
            [140 - 30] => 110
            [110 - 30] => 80
            [80 - 30] => 50
            [50 - 30] => 20
            [20 - 30] => 0
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi, I have this error ```Undefined offset: 2``` inside this loop 
```for($j=0; $j<count($nextRemainders); $j++) {
        $array[$j]['remainder'] += $nextRemainders[$j];
    }```

Comment: Hmm, not sure how that would happen unless your input keys are different than the example? Maybe try this: `foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $array[$key]['remainder'] += $nextRemainders[$key] ?? 0;
}` instead of the `for($j=0` loop